# \bar below symbol

Tags: symbols

Is there a command like `\bar{...}` but such that the bar is placed below the symbol?

Of course there is `\underline{...}` but then the line is adapted to the width of the symbol and I don't want that (compare with the difference between `\overline{...}` and `\bar{...}`).

I need this for math mode.

Comment: Do you need it in text mode or in math mode? Have a look at the `accents` package.

Comment: Maybe this from `amsmath`: `\underset{\bar{}}{A}`

Comment: @egreg That's good. Could you turn the comment into an answer please.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The `accents` package has the feature you're looking for:

```
\usepackage{accents}
\newcommand{\ubar}[1]{\underaccent{\bar}{#1}}
```

Why the `\newcommand`? Because you might change your mind or find a new way to underline a symbol, so you can just modify the definition instead of hunting through the document for occurrences of `\underaccent{\bar}`.

Comment: Interesting. With this we don't need to write `\bar{}` like mine suggestion. Also, the space between the symbol and the bar is different.

Comment: @Sigur The `accents` package ensures that the correct vertical dimension is assigned to the underaccent; with `\underset{\bar{}}{x}` you get a full vertical sized bar; and, moreover, it will be in script style.

Answer (score 26):

My solution is `\newcommand{\ubar}[1]{\text{\b{$#1$}}}` since I get a conflict of `accents` and `amsmath` packages concerning `\vec` command.

Comment: Can someone please explain why this has been downvoted? I am unsure if I should use the accents package in case there is indeed an assue with the amsmath package, as @SergeyPolyakovskiy suggests, however it is unclear. I have tried searching it in other questions and it seems that such a \vec issue does exist, but some clarification would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: This. This answer saved my hide. The solution that is accepted here -- and referenced seemingly everywhere when it comes to the problem of making a suitable underbar expression relies on a really outdated package that, as far as I can figure, was last updated in 2006. It is not compatible with amsmath and a host of other packages. This solution works tremendously well.

Answer (score 10):

You can play with the three parameters (1.2pt underset gap, .8ex rule length, .075ex rule width

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\barbelow[1]{\stackunder[1.2pt]{$#1$}{\rule{.8ex}{.075ex}}}
\( \overline{A} \bar{A} \barbelow{A} \)
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I needed to use a subscript with the \barbelow{f}, and this solution works the best - thanks! I used a slightly different set of parameters (1pt, .8ex, 0.075ex) though.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried using `\underbar{symbol}` in a math environment?

Comment: This only works in text mode.

Comment: Just used it in math environment! It does work!

Comment: For me using `\underbar` gives a bunch of weird errors having to do with closing math mode.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `\textrm{.1.}` for text mode IN the math mode. In the brackets you can then use the text mode command `\underline{.2.}` to underline your text input in the {.2.} brackets.

in math mode...

```
\textrm{\underline{this text input will be underlined}}
```

... worked for me

Answer (score 0):

This post was also very helpful for me as I've had a similar problem.
I am using `\bar` and this solution

```
\usepackage{stackengine}
\newcommand\barbelow[1]{\stackunder[1.2pt]{$#1$}{\rule{.8ex}{.075ex}}}
```

to underline in math mode. Unfortunately it seems like the `\ba`r commads provides a slightly thicker bar which is why I am wondering if there is a possibility to make `\barbelow` a little bit thicker as well?

Thanks in advanve :)

Comment: Hi, welcome. Please note that this site isn't like a normal forum. All answer-posts should contain solutions to the problem posed in the question-post. Follow-up questions, if not handled in comments should be asked via the Ask Question-link in the top right. That said, change `.075ex` to some higher value, the thickness of the bar is determined by that length.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I am sorry as I didn't know that before and appreciate your answer. Will do better with future comments :)